# Best way to access Apollo GraphQL client inside redux action creators?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, graphql, apollo

In the (untested) example code below, if I want to access an instance of the Apollo GraphQL client inside `actions/math.js`, I have to pass it from the `Calculator` component to event handlers, and from the `WrappedCalculator` event handlers to the action creators.

This results in a lot of code bloat.

What would be a better way for `actions/math.js` action creators to access the GraphQL client instance?

**Example code:**

**constants/Queries.js**:

```
const MUTATION_APPEND_TO_AUDIT_TRAIL = gql`
    mutation MutationAppendToAuditTrail($mathOperation: String!, $operand1: Float!, $operand2: Float!) {
        appendToAuditTrail(operation: $mathOperation, operand1: $operand1, operand2: $operand2) {
            id
            operation
            operand1
            operand2
        }
    }
`;
```

**actions/math.js**:

```
import { INCREMENT_TOTAL_BY, MULTIPLY_TOTAL_BY } from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import { getTotal } from '../reducers';

incrementResultBy = (operand, graphQlClient) => (dispatch, getState) {
    // Use selector to get the total prior to the operation.
    const total = getTotal(getState());

    // Send action to add a number to the total in the redux store.
    dispatch({
        type: types.INCREMENT_TOTAL_BY,
        operand,
    });

    // Persist the latest user activity to the server.
    graphQlClient.mutate({
        mutation: MUTATION_APPEND_TO_AUDIT_TRAIL,
        variables: {
            mathOperation: 'ADDITION',
            operand1: total,
            operand2: operand,
          },
        });
};

multiplyResultBy = (operand, graphQlClient) => (dispatch, getState) {
    // Use selector to get the total prior to the operation.
    const total = getTotal(getState());

    // Send action to multiply the total in the redux store by a number.
    dispatch({
        type: types.MULTIPLY_TOTAL_BY,
        operand,
    });

    // Persist the latest user activity to the server.
    graphQlClient.mutate({
        mutation: MUTATION_APPEND_TO_AUDIT_TRAIL,
        variables: {
            mathOperation: 'MULTIPLICATION',
            operand1: total,
            operand2: operand,
          },
        });
};

export { incrementResultBy, multiplyResultBy };
```

**components/Calculator.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';

const Calculator = ({
  total,
  operand,
  onPlusButtonClick,
  onMultiplyButtonClick,
}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Perform operation for {total} and {operand}</h2>
    <button id="ADD" onClick={onPlusButtonClick(() => this.props.operand, this.props.client)}>ADD</button><br />
    <button id="MULTIPLY" onClick={() => onMultiplyButtonClick(this.props.operand, this.props.client)}>MULTIPLY</button><br />
  </div>
);

DisplayPanel.propTypes = {
  // Apollo GraphQL client instance.
  client: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(ApolloClient),

  // Props from Redux.
  total: React.PropTypes.number,
  operand: React.PropTypes.number,
  onPlusButtonClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  onMultiplyButtonClick: React.PropTypes.func,
};
export default Calculator;
```

**containers/WrappedCalculator.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Calculator from '../components/Calculator';

import { incrementResultBy, multiplyResultBy } from '../actions';
import { getTotal, getOperand } from '../reducers';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  total: getTotal(state),
  operand: getOperand(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onPlusButtonClick: (operand, graphQlClient) => dispatch(incrementResultBy(operand, graphQlClient)),
  onMultiplyButtonClick: (operand, graphQlClient) => dispatch(multiplyResultBy(operand, graphQlClient)),
});

// Generate Apollo-aware, redux-aware higher-order container.
const WrappedCalculator = compose(
  withApollo,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(Calculator);

export default WrappedCalculator;
```

Comment: Possibly a little late... but since queries and mutations are async, you'd need to use the thunk middleware. Thunk middleware conveniently allows you to supply an extra arg to action creators - so you could configure it to supply the client as an extra arg. See: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument

Answer (score 5):

One thing that I've done to pass around an ApolloClient instance is to wrap the ApolloClient in a Provider like so:

**ApolloClientProvider.js**

```
class ApolloClientProvider {

  constructor() {
    this.client = new ApolloClient({
      networkInterface: '/graphql'
    })
  }
}

export default new ApolloClientProvider()
```

This will create a singleton like instance of the ApolloClient and wherever you reference it from will return the same ApolloClient that was initialized when the ApolloClientProvider was first referenced.

```
import ApolloClientProvider from 'ApolloClientProvider'
const client = ApolloClientProvider.client
```

Answer (score 3):

In your index.js file, you have `const client = new ApolloClient({...})`:

instead make it `export const client = new ApolloClient({...})`

And import it as `import { client } from './index'`, or you can pass through all the props.

Answer (score 0):

Based on wmcbain answer I also created and registered a client provider:

**ApolloClientProvider.ts**

```
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from "apollo-client";
export class ApolloClientProvider {

client: ApolloClient;

constructor(private settings: Settings) {
  this.client = new ApolloClient({
     networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
       uri: "https://myGraphQLServer/api/data"
     })
  })
 }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
//register the provider
app.service("apolloClientProvider", ApolloClientProvider);
```

**clientService.ts**

```
class ClientService {

apolloClient: ApolloClient;

constructor(private apolloClientProvider: ApolloClientProvider) {
    this.apolloClient = apolloClientProvider.client;
}
```

This code uses apollo-client (v 1.1.1)