# How can I fetch per Apollo client to create dynamic drawer routes (React Navigation)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-apollo, apollo-client

I cannot use the `client` inside my creation of navigation items.

**1. I create my Apollo stuff and return**

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <AppContainer />
</ApolloProvider>
```

**2. `AppContainer` is in a separate file**

```
createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator)
```

**3. `AppDrawerNavigator` is in a separate file**

```
createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack: {
      screen: HomeStackNavigator
    },
    ...drawerRoutes
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeStack',
    drawerPosition: 'right'
  }
);
```

**4. `drawerRoutes` is an hard coded object**

```
const drawerRoutes = {
  First: {
    screen: IndexStackNavigator
  },
  Second: {
    screen: IndexStackNavigator
  }
};
```

Now I want to dynamically create the `drawerRoutes` after querying the Apollo client.
But I did not manage to access the client inside `createDrawerNavigator`.
Also I cannot pass something down to the `createDrawerNavigator`. Is there a tricky way to do that?
Best would be to create the `drawerRoutes` in the 1. step an than pass down the route object to the 3. step.

When I put Apollo client creation, React Navigation Drawer creation and everything in one file, it is working. But the file gets messy.

Can anybody help? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand correctly you just need to export your apollo client and import it wherever you need it, For instance:

```js
// ApolloClient.js

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  ...
});
```

```js
// WhereYouNeedClient.js

import { client } from './ApolloClient'
...
```

Comment: Isn't it created newly again and again on every import in this way?

Comment: Apparently there is a [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496128/9503011) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked it yet, but it seems, that `ApolloConsumer` is the way to access the `client` in children components of the `ApolloProvider`:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries/#manually-firing-a-query